# Code to find cells that contain a constant preceded by = sign

Tags: excel, vba

Any suggestions for Excel vba code that will identify cells that contain values but no function. The catch being that the values I'm searching for are preceded by an "=" sign.

I often have to review other people's financial spreadsheets and knowing which cells contain the actual inputs (assumptions) is key. I can easily find cells with just a constant input with a simple:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
```

The problem is some users have a habit of inputing numbers preceded by an = sign and these cells are treated by excel as containing a function. I know I can search for cells with functions too, but I only want to find the ones that don't actually have a function, but are input starting with an = sign.

In other words, instead of inputing 1000 in a cell the user inputs =1000. It is only these types of cells I am trying to highlight.

Any suggestions on how I can identify these cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly this *"The problem is some users have a habit of inputing numbers preceded by an = sign"* is your problem. Stop people having this habit!

1. First it is a stupid habit because it slows everything down because Excel has to evaluate those cells that contain something like `=1000` to find out the value and
2. second those cells actually contain a formula and not a value. So there is no built in way to distinguish them.

Those people are just using Excel wrong.

There is only one workaround I can imagine and that is looping through all cells that contain a formula, remove the `=` sign and check if the rest of the *"formula"* is numeric `IsNumeric()`. If so replace the formula by its value.

So for example if the cell is `=1000` then `1000` is numeric and it will replace it by the value `1000`. If the cell is `=1000*2` then `1000*2` is not numeric because it contains a `*` sign and it will keep the formula.

Note that this workaround is just fighting symptoms but not fixing the root cause. The root cause is those people using Excel wrong! And you should always fix the causes not fight the symptoms.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceFormluasWithValueIfNoCalculation()
    Dim AllCellsWithFormulas As Range
    On Error Resume Next  ' next line errors if no formulas are found, so hide errors
    Set AllCellsWithFormulas = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0  ' re-enable error reporting
    
    If Not AllCellsWithFormulas Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Variant
        For Each Cell In AllCellsWithFormulas.Cells  ' loop through all formulas
            Dim ExtractedValue As String  ' extract formula right of the `=` sign
            ExtractedValue = Right$(Cell.Formula, Len(Cell.Formula) - 1)
            ' check if extracted formula is only a value, if so replace formula with value
            If IsNumeric(ExtractedValue) Then
                Cell.Value = ExtractedValue
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

<sup>Even the above can be done, I recommend fixing the root cause.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Peh. You are more subdued on how you refer to these "people" than I am.

Unfortunately I can't fix the root cause as they are not my people. They are either clients, funding institutions or other entitites with which my client is interacting.

Comment: Peh, your code is almost perfect for me - many thanks. But I've just discovered it doesn't find cells where the "genius" who created the model inputs percentage numbers preceded by the = sign.

In other words, rather than formatting a cell as a percentage cell and inputing "1" to get a 1.00% value they input "=1%" in a cell formatted as a percentage. Yes, I'm shaking my head too.

Any suggestions on how to get the code to also identify the cells with the % sign in them?

Comment: Well you can try using `If IsNumeric(Replace$(ExtractedValue, "%", vbNullString)) Then` instead. So the `%` gets stripped off to see if the rest is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those inputs only contain number you could use a regex for that and ensure the value only contain "=" and numbers you'll have a code like this :

```
    Dim RegEx As Object, MyString As String
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    MyString = cell.formulas

    With RegEx
      .Pattern = "=*[0-9., ]+"
    End With

    RegEx.test(MyString) 'True if MyString is a number false if it's a function
```

You'll need to activate "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression" though.

Comment: Might also want to check for negative numbers, as well as numbers in the format `6.0223E+23`.

Comment: Actually that's why `IsNumeric` is much easier. You don't have to cover all those extra cases. If you use a RexEx you have to recognize `6.0223E+23` and make sure `6.0223+23` is not handled as a value but a formula. It will get a way more complicated to run all those edge cases.